# Android build gradle fail

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i've been working on a app for a while, and took a few days off, now i'm trying to run it and i'm getting these 7 failures... I tried to check compile history and theirs no changes. So i'm confused as to why its not working all of the sudden. This is probably a pretty easy problem to fix, but i know really nothing about android development..

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 7 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/2.1.0/extensions-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0
   > Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
       - https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/2.1.0/runtime-2.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "###########"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0")
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01'
    implementation('com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0')
}
```

build.gradle (appname)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        // This private repository is required to resolve the Cardinal SDK transitive dependency.
        maven {
            url  "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
            credentials {
                // Be sure to add these non-sensitive credentials in order to retrieve dependencies from
                // the private repository.
                username 'paypal_sgerritz'
                password 'AKCp8jQ8tAahqpT5JjZ4FRP2mW7GMoFZ674kGqHmupTesKeAY2G8NcmPKLuTxTGkKjDLRzDUQ'
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and then rebuilding? Closing and reopening the project? Closing and reopening Android Studio? If this was working just a few days ago then you could be dealing with a bug in Android Studio. Check for any dependency issues or any prompts in the bottom right corner for any updates.

Comment: True @Nathan. Good comment

Comment: @NathanMeade I didn't even know that existed, I'm trying out the different options and seeing what will work!

Comment: So, the problem is coming in with the PayPal stuff apparently, even though it worked a few day's ago.... But when i delete paypal out of it, it works just fine....

Answer (score 1):

`File -> Invalidate Cache & Restart`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to copy and paste your code to a new android studio project but if nothing's changed it's probably android studio being android studio. Maybe try not using the emulator and running the app on your phone as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line. ````Could not find android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0.`````
As you can see it is saying that could not find Android.arch.lifecycle.  The problem is with your Gradle. Try running a new empty project and if it works, the problem is with your build.gradle file. You might have written a wrong line or configured it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times those errors can be fixed by cleaning and rebuilding the project. So give it a try, Go to Build>Clean project. Then go to Build > Rebuild Project. There was a case a month ago where i had to delete the jcenter() repository for the problem to be fixed. Another thing that you should probably check is a possible android studio update. Last but not least check your dependencies for an version mismatch.